# error while building paypal here sdk

Tags: android, google-play-services, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I'm trying to add the paypal here sdk to my app. Their sample app works with no problem. So I used it as an example, built a mid-tier server, and got my app requesting tokens from it. Now the issue is that I get the following error when I try to initialize the SDK

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.bistrobot.bistrobot, PID: 17506
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.isConnected()' was expected to be of type interface but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.paypal.merchant.sdk.internal.service.GooglePlayLocationServiceImpl.startLocationService(GooglePlayLocationServiceImpl.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.paypal.merchant.sdk.internal.SDKCore.init(SDKCore.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.paypal.merchant.sdk.PayPalHereSDK.init(PayPalHereSDK.java:163)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bistrobot.bistrobot.sdk.PayPalHereSDKWrapper.initializeSDK(PayPalHereSDKWrapper.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bistrobot.bistrobot.login.LoginActivity.startPaymentOptionsActivity(LoginActivity.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bistrobot.bistrobot.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
```

Based on the error, I think the sdk can't get my location so it doesn't have access to it but I have google play services in my gradle file. Here are my android manifest and build.gradle just in case someone could point in the right direction. FYI, the sdk is added as a module so that's why it doesn't show the attached build gradle.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_transparent"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".login.DeviceListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DEATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
</application>
```

**Build.grade**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bistrobot.bistrobot"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
compile project(':usbSerialForAndroid')
compile project(':PayPalHereSDK')
}
```

Comment: The problem comes from one of the libraries your app depends on, library that depends itself on `Google Play Services` as well. The solution is that Look if that library you use has a new updated version with `8.1.0` as well, or remove that dependency if possible. For more details, please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33104033).

Comment: I ended up downgrading actually to an older play service version and it worked just fine. It was the matter of the app not being compatible with Google Play Service 8.1.0. So you are absolutely right. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from one of the libraries your app depends on, library that depends itself on `Google Play Services` as well. The solution is that Look if that library you use has a new updated version with `8.1.0` as well, or remove that dependency if possible. For more details, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073779/googleapiclient-connect-was-expected-to-be-of-type-interface-but-was-found-to/33104033#33104033).

Also, you can try downgrading actually to an older play service version and it worked just fine. It was the matter of the app not being compatible with `Google Play Service 8.1.0`.